# jQuery Tools Scrollable not quite working - neither the navigate nor mousewheel functions work

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the jQuery Tools Scrollable plugin - http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable.html#navigator

I have created a scrollable with a navigator before without problems and now, for some reason I cannot get the darned thing to work. The possible reason could be that there are too many divs playing, but I need all of them because each scrollable needs a container.

I cannot get the navigator and the mousewheel elements to work. I'm sure it is something really simple that I have missed so I would really appreciate it if someone could have a look through my code and figure out what I'm missing.

Please have a look at  http://jsbin.com/inuru/ to see where I'm at so far.

You can play around and have a look at the code here: http://jsbin.com/inuru/edit/

Many thanks in advance

Comment: clicking the arrows or the text works for me in FF3.5.5. - but I do get text, not images (e.g. the path to the images doesn't work)

Comment: I know, that is on purpose. We wouldn't want you seeing my site's images before launch would we now.. thanks for taking the time to look at my problem

Comment: @Zander : I am just trying to implement multiple navigator plugin on my page like your example on http://jsbin.com/inuru/...But I am facing many issues..Just single navigator works fine...But cannot get 2 to work on the same HTML like you have...Could you please guide me on how I can make 2 nav plugins work on a single html ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The script you're linking to is a minimal one that doesn't include `tools.scrollable.navigator`. You need to [build a script](http://flowplayer.org/tools/download.html) containing that and any others of the tools you want to use, or just link to the [full build](http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.1.2/full/jquery.tools.min.js) if you don't care about the bloat.

Answer (score 1):

Is it because you haven't included the mousewheel jquery plugin - [mousewheel jquery plugin](http://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel) - which jquery tools rely on?

Comment: How did I not notice that? thank you so much for taking the time to investigate.